# Button in email redirecting to `about:blank` with valid link

Tags: html

Seeing some strange behavior in an email template where, upon click on a button with a valid s3 link, I get redirected to `about:blank`, then redirected back to my email. If I inspect this button I see:

```
<a href="https://example.com" style="font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#005589;text-decoration:none" target="_blank">
      <button style="background-color:#005589;border-radius:4px;color:#fff;font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;height:56px;padding:21px 70px;border:0">
            Download Report
      </button>
</a>
```

The link points to an S3 address instead of example.com. When I go into dev tools and click the link directly from the I get redirected and the file downloads automatically no problem. When I click the button directly in the email it doesn't work. Any ideas as to what could be going on here?

Updated HTML:

```
<a href="http://example.com" style="font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;background-color:#005589;border-radius:4px;color:#fff;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;height:56px;text-decoration:none;padding:21px 70px;border:0">Download Report</a>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Links may not contain buttons, or vice versa.

Comment: you can style your href to look like a button

Comment: @Quentin I've updated my HTML to the following above. Like I said this is an S3 auto download link. After this change, it works just fine in Safari but does the same `about:blank` redirect in Chrome.